# How to add a View with style and props? (JSX Syntax)

Tags: react-native

New JavaScript and React Native user here. This seems so simple it's embarrassing to ask, but I'm having no luck finding related documentation or examples.

I'm trying to set up a view from a custom component class, but I can't figure out how to avoid a SyntaxError when I assign the view a style and props. Here's the line with the error:

```
<MyView {myWidth=500}, style={backgroundColor: 'blue'}>
</MyView>
```

The exact Error is : "SyntaxError App.js: Unexpected token, expected ... (144:23)"

I know 144 is the line number, but I'm not sure what the significance is of the number 23.

Here is the custom component class:

```
class MyView extends React.Component {

  render() {

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        width: this.props.myWidth,
      }}
    >
    </View>
  );
 }
}
```

Can you please help me fix the error?  I would also greatly appreciate a link to applicable React Native documentation that I missed.

Answer (score 0):

It's:

```
<MyView myWidth={500}, style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}></MyView>
```

So `myWidth` is key (or prop) where 500 is the value, and style has an *Object* with key and value for styling.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting an error: "SyntaxError App.js: Unexpected token (144:35)"